# Гугл таблицы - отловить клик по любой ячейке

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть Гугл таблица.
При клике по любой ячейке столбца "A"  всегда в ячейке "B1"  должен отобразиться номер строки по ячейке из которой кликнули.

Ориентировочно - несколько тысяч строк в таблице будет.

для чего это - см ссылку https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OQc1rmNoYdP_8MfDGhoNb5acsKPghnn8vNRdjb5dbys/edit?usp=sharing

Основной вопрос - такое реально реализовать? Тормоза, глюки - полезут или нет?

Реализовать аналог на PHP + HTML особых проблем нет, но интересует именно реализация на гугл таблицах + Apps Script ?

Заранее спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете взаимодействовать с интерфейсом без собственной внешней обертки.
Использование подобных оберток, хоть и не запрещено, но не предусмотрено вендором.

Примеры такого взаимодействия

#### Google Sheets Row Highlighter

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/google-sheets-row-highlig/cejijldbedfmdehondfmoadlkhgjcmkd

- Рисует поверх Таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Black Apps Script

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/black-apps-script/lobpcflajoikohefjjdndofbfikadpfb

- Не Таблицы, но тоже самое, поверх проекта Скрипта разворачивает IDE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Если кто-то скажет, что триггеры - это взаимодействие с интерфейсом, можете смело есть его печень - он вам враг.*